# IIS throwig error when im refrencing a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

im messing around with a master page, and i want to use jquery and another javascript file to a simple tamplate im creating.

i have a wierd problem that i dont understand, when i run the apsx on the browser, i dont see the changes i made in the javascript file. 
when i looking at the code [view source on chrome] and try to see the code on the javascript file and the jquery 1, i get an error

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that
>   contains a double escape sequence.

this is how i refrence the fiels in the head element:

```
<head runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Jquery1.6+vsdoc/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
```

> 

what can be the problem?

im using visual studio 2012 if that helps.
(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the name of your Javasdcript file to not include a plus in it.

`../Jquery1.6+vsdoc/jquery-1.7.1.min.js`

to

`../Jquery1.6_vsdoc/jquery-1.7.1.min.js`

That plus is a double escape and by default is blocked in IIS.

Comment: @samy that is correct, unless you disable to double escape filter, but I wouldn't recommend it.